# Error importing a remote next js app into react host app with webpack module federation

Tags: reactjs, next.js, webpack-module-federation

I am facing an issue with my React application acting as a host using Module Federation. The RemoteEntry.js is successfully loaded according to the network tab, but I encounter a runtime error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')

Key Details:

- RemoteEntry.js is loaded in the network tab.
- The error occurs when trying to access properties of the remotely loaded component.
- I am using React.lazy for dynamic imports.

Here is the webpack config of react host app:

```
  const NEXT_REMOTE_URL = "http://localhost:3000";
  const CLONE_REMOTE_URL = "http://localhost:5000";

  config.plugins?.push(
    new webpack.container.ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "react-host",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      remotes: {
        "next-remote": `next-remote@${NEXT_REMOTE_URL}/_next/static/chunks/remoteEntry.js`,
        clone: `clone@${CLONE_REMOTE_URL}/_next/static/chunks/remoteEntry.js`,
      },
      exposes: {},
      shared: {
        ...PackageJson.dependencies,
        react: {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: PackageJson.dependencies["react"],
        },
        // "react-router-dom": {
        //   eager: true,
        //   requiredVersion: PackageJson.dependencies["react-router-dom"],
        // },
        // "react-dom": {
        //   eager: true,
        //   requiredVersion: PackageJson.dependencies["react-dom"],
        // },
      },
    })
  );

  return config;
```

Next config:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const NextFederationPlugin = require("@module-federation/nextjs-mf");

const nextConfig = {
  webpack: (config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, webpack }) => {
    config.plugins.push(
      new NextFederationPlugin({
        name: "clone",
        filename: "static/chunks/remoteEntry.js",
        exposes: {
          "./clonedArt": "./pages/clonedArticles.tsx",
        },
        shared: {},
      })
    );
    return config;
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Importing the remote next app inside app.tsx

```
const NextClone = lazy(
  () =>
   
    import("clone/clonedArt")
);
 <Suspense fallback="Loading..."> 
        <NextClone />
      </Suspense>
```

A strange thing is that if i use next as host and import another next or react, everything is good, but in this case bug [network status code 200 but err](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTPJy.png)

If you wanna see full code you can get it here: https://github.com/Mindsurfer7/MSCMircoservices

There are 2 branches: main is where next is host and switching-host-with-remote where the host is react.